# Can you force all rows to show on screen?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, razor

I have a simple bootstrap application, I don't have a problem with the columns width but the row size is bugging me. Is there a way to change the height of rows? I've tried using

```
.row {
     height: 20px;
}
```

and it's just too static, I've got rows of varying height and this just confuses things. Ideally, I'd like a table that when you add new rows to it, it resizes and all rows fit on the screen. But I'd happily settle for if I'm on a big screen 20 rows show, if I'm on a smaller screen 10 rows show. So far, all screens show the same amount of rows.

The razor code that generates the table:

```
                    foreach (var order in Model)
                    {
                        <div class="row order row-height item-row" id="orderid">
                            <div class="col-md-3 text-center order-text">
                                <p>@order.TimeOrdered</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-3 text-center order-text">
                                <p>@order.Orderer</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-3 text-center order-text">
                                <p>@order.Destination</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-3 text-center order-text">
                                <p class="status">@order.Remarks1</p>
                            </div>
                            <hr />
                        </div>

                    }
```

Thank you in advance for any help/guidance.

Comment: If you want all rows to be the same height, you could use JavaScript to get the row with the most height, and set all rows to match that height. Otherwise you'd have to fight with min-height.

Comment: Hi! I'm sorry I was unclear. I don't necessarily want them to be the same height. I just want more rows to show on a bigger screen OR all rows to show with no scrolling. Thank you for your suggestion though. I think I can try some things with it.

Comment: Gotcha. Maybe you can look at css media queries to fulfill your needs.

Comment: That's a good idea! I'll take a look at that and using VH units.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there are a few different approaches you could take..

**1) Flexbox**

```
.fill-rows {
    min-height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.fill-rows > .row  {
    width: 100%;
    flex: 1;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
}

/* set a min-max height on row contents */
.col-md-3 {
   min-height: 30px;
   max-height: 50px;
}
```

http://www.codeply.com/go/zP8vdOcdPX

***OR***

**2) `vh` Units - 10% of height**

```
.fill-rows > .row  {
    height: 10vh;
}
```

http://www.codeply.com/go/Sx9jbiwc1R

Also there are height-based media queries to control element styles at specific viewport heights.

Comment: Thank you Zim, I will check this out and reply with how it worked.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you look into CSS3 units VH. You could theoretically adjust TD padding to be in VH units, so the rows scale to screen better.  Likely you will need a table with pagination then.  ListJS is ok.

Here's an example: https://codepen.io/trinzia/pen/BLRXZK

```
table { height:calc(100vh - 80px); }

tbody td { 
  padding:5.5vh 9px;
}
```

If you need to actually hide rows too (although I have a hard time imagining when this would be good, see http://codepen.io/giodif/pen/LjwFi.  Height-based media queries should help.

Comment: Thank you, I'll definitely take a look!